# Supplying build info as qx.core.Environment entries

Tags: qooxdoo

I have my qooxdoo project built and deployed by a CI server. Upon build, the server generates build info (version, VCS revision, CI build number, timestamp) that I would like to be passed to my qooxdoo app as `qx.core.Environment` keys.

At the moment, I have CI server generate a `build.json` file which is packaged together with the application, loaded at startup and converted to environment keys (by application code). This costs us an extra XHR.

On the other hand, I know that environment entries can be supplied during build, via `config.json`. Of course our build system can preprocess `config.json` to fill in environment entries, but I'm a bit skeptic of the idea of CI server fiddling with `config.json`. Is there any better solution? Is it possible to make generator script read environment entries from some auxiliary source?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a #VERSION# tag into my script and at the end of the build process just search and replace this string in the compiled js file.

```
perl -i -p -e 's/#VERSION#/0.3.0/g' build/script/hello.js
```

Comment: In my case, the build is driven by Maven, which is itself capable of token substitution (via so called resource filtering), so no need for Perl. I would probably avoid messing with the generated script, however, the idea sounds interesting. Probably I could generate a (static) qooxdoo class that would contain build info and would put it into qx.core.Environment. I'll give it a try.